# US-Production Version?

Tags: american-english

> Hyundai is unveiling the US-production version of it's [sic] convention-shattering KONA crossover at the Los Angeles Auto Show. For those unable to attend the show, a live stream of the press conference will be available.
>                           — [source](https://www.hyundainews.com)

I have a question to native English speaker. My first language is not English.

In the above paragraph, Hyundai says it is unveiling the US-production version of Kona. To me, who does not speak English as a first language, "US-production version" is understood as a version of Kona produced in the US plant. But, some people say it simply means Kona produced for the US, which means it does not necessarily mean "it is produced in the US".

What is correct understanding?

Comment: "US-production" implies that it is manufactured / assembled in the US. "US model" could be made elsewhere. Remember that advertising uses suggestion, hype, and almost-thruth. The way to find the truth here, it to research the *actual factory* in the US where it is made.

Comment: I think the word *version* strongly suggests the second meaning to native speakers. The US has its own set of vehicle safety standards that require quite a bit of tinkering to comply with. *US produced* would be the idiomatic way to refer to it being assembled in the US.

Comment: I can say that we almost exclusively use "manufactured in" and "made in" to indicate something is built in the US. This convergence of terms probably comes from the fields of marketing and politics. However, like another commenter noted, it's best to do more research since these days products and their components are designed, manufactured, and assembled in different countries.

Comment: What @user267914 said. The phrase is ambiguous, and perhaps intentionally misleading - designed to suggest that it is produced in the US, without stating that clearly (presumably because it is not).

Answer (score 2):

It can seem ambiguous unless you're familiar with the way these terms are commonly used.

The Kona will be manufactured exclusively in South Korea. [LINK](http://www.al.com/business/index.ssf/2017/06/hyundai_unveils_plans_for_kona.html)
"Production version" means that it's the version of the car intended for sale to the public, as opposed to an experimental car, pre-production version, prototype or concept car. [HERE](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-drive/auto-shows/north-america/audi-previews-hybrid-q8-concept-production-version-set-for-2018/article33549260/) you can see an example of how the industry uses the term. U.S.-production version means it's the production version intended for sale in the U.S., as opposed to the versions which will be sold in Europe, South America, etc.